# Error on launching wpf application which is deployed using ClickOnce

Tags: wpf, prism, unity-container, clickonce

I'm using Prism.Unity [Template Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BrianLagunas.PrismTemplatePack&ssr=false#qna) for my wpf application. Every thing works fine when I run the code within visual studio. But after deployment below error is being thrown on application launch. Tried looking around but couldn't understand how to fix Verification exception.

Since prism has Unity integrated within the library hence I could not able debug it. Also I looked into the source code from github and didn't find any clue.

Event Log:

> Application: applaunch.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.Security.VerificationException
>      at Unity.Storage.Registrations..ctor(Int32)
>      at Unity.UnityContainer..ctor()
>      at Prism.Unity.PrismApplication.CreateContainerExtension()
>      at Prism.PrismApplicationBase.Initialize()
>      at Prism.PrismApplicationBase.InitializeInternal()
>      at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(System.Object)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
>      at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
>      at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
>      at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
>      at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
>      at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
>      at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
>      at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>      at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>      at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
>      at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
>      at PrismUploadUI.App.Main()
>      at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.String[])
>      at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.NewThreadRunner()
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: People who are voting for close please mentioned the reason here as i'm clue less about this issue.

Comment: What does "I cannot debug" mean? What makes you think anyone else could debug better?

Comment: its throwing error in Unity container which is coming from library that I cannot debug. I didn't mean for asking to debug it for me but hoping if anyone got into this issue before and could give me a clue.

Comment: Can you enable break on `System.Security.VerificationException` to see where it occurs when you start debugging it?

Comment: project runs fine when via visual studio, but fails to launch after deployment. The above error is what I get in event logs.

Comment: Have you used the remote debugger? Have you checked that the correct dlls are deployed? Have you checked that the correct framework is installed? Have you checked permissions?

Comment: Yes I did. I'm really stupid that I was looking in a wrong direction. So many answers were there and everyone's problem got fixed by changing manifest settings. In my case some how csproj file wasn't getting reflected what ever I'm selected at UI settings..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody facing this issue, I got it fixed and it is nothing to do with prism template nor any related to prism unity, it was due few tags within .csproj file that was causing this issue.

Removing `<TargetZone>LocalIntranet</TargetZone>` fixed my issue but I still don't understand how this tag is not getting removed even after I set this as **full trusted** in application properties of the project. One more thing was I did set manifest setting as create application without a manifest and yet I found this tag as `<GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>` in csproj. I made it false then.

So guys do also check csproj file for what it is getting added.